# Laravel: attach needs to be followed by load?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

For this example, consider models `User` and `Comment` with a many-to-many relationship.

In the user model:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Now, I add a comment for the user:

`$user->comments()->attach($comment)`

This line adds the entry to the database pivot table.

However if I now check the value of `$user->comments` it is still `[]`. I end up having to do something like this in order to keep the object up to date:

```
$user->comments()->attach($comment);
echo $user->comments; // []
$user->load('comments');
echo $user->comments; // [ {id => 1, ...} ]
```

Feels weird and redundant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way of doing `->load()` is the most precise and in some cases, accurate.

Your `echo $user->comments` will check if you have already loaded the comments relationship (ie: called `$user->comments` earlier in this request or used something like `->with('comments')`). I assume you have, before attaching the comment, and calling it again will just return the comments originally loaded (this prevents every call to the relationship from executing a new query).

Using `->load(..)` will execute a query that will refresh the comments and give you updated results.

**However**! If you would like to save yourself from executing this additional query, since you already have all the data - you can.

You can attach the newly added comment to the comments relation (a collection) manually:

```
$user->comments()->attach($comment);
$user->comments->push($comment); // Will manually add the new comment to the existing collection
```

Again, however, there could be some unintended consequences using the above method. Such as, if the `comments` table has some columns that make use of SQL default values and were not explicitly assigned when creating the comment, you won't see those.

So, tldr: unless performance is vital and you can't afford that additional query, I'd stick to your original solution.

Comment: If only they'd return the pivot created in the attach method..

Answer (score 0):

Run this before trying to access comments again:

```
$user->refresh();
```

Not sure if this feels less weird to you but it's a clean way of refreshing all user attributes and relations from the db.

Comment: That's definitely cleaner than doing a load. But how come I need to do a `refresh` altogether? I don't need to do that when I use `associate`?

Comment: Associate is actually updating the object that it's called on with some kind of 'relation'_id field where attach is updating an intermediate table in the DB.  That's the only logical reason I can think of but I agree it seems weird and would probably save a lot of headaches if attach refreshed the current object.

Comment: or at least updated the object with that one comment

Comment: `$user->refresh()` will refresh the user. Which is an unneeded query as attaching the comment doesn't change the user object (unless you explicitly told it to with something like `$touches`).

Comment: The user object in memory not being changed by the attach call is precisely why you may want to call refresh, to bring in the newly attached relations

Comment: `->load(..relations)` will do that (bring newly attached relations). `$user->refresh()` will refresh the user object, which is unchanged in this situation. So an unnecessary query.

Comment: Running refresh and then attempting to access any previously attached relations will pull them in as well,  do you not beleive this works or are you arguing that load is better for this specific case?

Comment: I'm arguing load is better for this specific case as it executes (at least) 1 less query while retrieving all the information OP is asking for in their question. I understand using refresh works too.